# In ASP.NET MVC, why does the ViewContext have a Writer property?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Looking at the source, I see that a ViewContext is instantiated inside the ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult() method and is passed a writer.

```
ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(context, this.View, this.ViewData, this.TempData, output);
```

But when the view is rendered the writer is passed into the View.Render() method and I believe that is on purpose, so that view engines other than the WebForms view engine can render into that writer.

```
this.View.Render(viewContext, output);
```

So what is the purpose of the writer that's part of the ViewContext?

Answer (score 2):

So you can grab the output of a view and do whatever you need with it.  A good example is using the viewengine to render HTML templated emails.

Comment: Yup. Rendering a view to a string for emails is probably the main use I can think of off the top of my head.

Comment: Isn't that what the second argument is for?